# How to use EMF Databinding for an implicit inverse relationship

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-databinding

I have an Ecore model with classes A and B. This model can not be changed. 
A has a many-to-one reference to B. B has no reference to A.
I would like to display a tree with Bs at the root and As as leaves. I would like to use EMF data binding. All examples I have seen assume that there is a list feature of the root to observe. However, in my scenario, there is no feature for this direction (i.e. B_to_A), only one for the reverse direction.

How do I create an Observable that observes B and notifies of changes of the As?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism for doing this. I have received a response from Tom Schindl: http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2009/06/06/galileo-emf-databinding-part-1/

> unfortunately there’s no way. You’d have to define eOpposites